# Cookie deletion issues when using IE

Tags: php

Okay, my site is written in PHP. I'm having problems with IE sometimes not deleting the cookies. Here's my log out code.

```
setcookie("user", "", time() - 50000000);

setcookie("pass", "", time() - 50000000);

header("Location: index.php");
```

This works great in Firefox, Chrome, etc. But IE sometimes won't delete the cookies?

My login when setting cookies looks like this:

```
setcookie("user", $result['Handle'], time() + 50000000);

setcookie("pass", $pass, time() + 50000000);

header("Location: news.php");
```

I just don't understand why it will clear it most of the time, but gets stuck other times.

Comment: I suspect it's possibly reading the negative number for time wrong.  You only need it to be some point in the past, try significantly lowering that 50000000

Comment: another possibility is maybe sometimes your header() is executing before cookie has a chance to be deleted. Could also try executing header() only after setcookie() is run.  wrap in condition sort of thing

Comment: Thanks, I tried both methods, and it still gets stuck. This is weird. It works fine in firefox, and even IE, but sometimes gets stuck.

Comment: Such a headache. My phone(windows phone 7) gets stuck when using IE and even the desktop version(9) sometimes keeps the user logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful you are not setting cookie at different directory levels.  This will effectively create two cookies for the same domain but with one set for a sub-directory/path.  I.e. www.example.com vs. www.example.com/mypath.  It is possible you set the cookie for a sub-path in addition to the root and are now deleting only the cookie for the sub-directory so the root cookie remains.  I don't believe this would be an IE specific behavior though.